# TYPO3 video media player Extension

Tags: media-player, typo3

Hope u got a great christmas.

I need to add some video media files to my TYPO3 site.
I have the media in mp4, webm, flv so i know that I can play the video in any browser i use.

My question is now...

If I run TYPO3 v. 6.1 FLUID/EXTBASE what extension can U then recommend to use, thats work 100% and where i can add same video in diffrent file/format, thats work with HTML5 and that can be added in the element content ?

I have tried the JW Player 4.5 extension, but can see it need a licens file to work, and then its OLD, can see the new version of JW Player is 6.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why ppl thinks it's funny to add minus rep. learn to write why u add this.

ppl. thats works with TYPO3. version 6.x know that the media content element is not working and u need to use other alternativ.

But i found the best Extension that works on HTML5 and FLASH and can do what i need.
[HTML5 Video Player](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/html5videoplayer/1.3.1/view/1/1/#idm272640)

Answer (score 1):

To have everything run for 100% on as much as devices i still recommend you to use YouTube or Vimeo for showing vid's. Also for changes in the standards they take away much pain.

But if you want giving a change try [this one](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/html5videoplayer/1.3.1/Index.html).

Good luck

Comment: yes as I ended up using, but yes u are right about YouTube and/or Vimeo.